# Apache Airflow operator to transfer data files from S3 to Azure blob

Tags: amazon-s3, airflow, azure-blob-storage

I'm looking for an Apache Airflow operator that could transfer the data files from AWS S3 bucket to Azure Blob storage. Similar to ADF copy activity in Azure where we can copy data from S3 bucket to Azure blob storage via the linked service.

Is there a similar functinality available in Apache Airflow via any particular operator. Upon quick research i could see **AzureBlobStorageToGCSOperator** that we can transfer files from Blob to google cloud, is there a particular operator that can transfer files from S3 to Blob. Any pointers would help.

```
with DAG(
"example_azure_blob_to_gcs",
schedule_interval=None,
start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),  # Override to match your needs
default_args={"container_name": AZURE_CONTAINER_NAME, "blob_name": BLOB_NAME},
) as dag:

wait_for_blob = WasbBlobSensor(task_id="wait_for_blob")

transfer_files_to_gcs = AzureBlobStorageToGCSOperator(
    task_id="transfer_files_to_gcs",
    # AZURE arg
    file_path=GCP_OBJECT_NAME,
    # GCP args
    bucket_name=GCP_BUCKET_NAME,
    object_name=GCP_OBJECT_NAME,
    filename=GCP_BUCKET_FILE_PATH,
    gzip=False,
    delegate_to=None,
    impersonation_chain=None,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no operator available as of now to copy data from S3 to azure blob storage.

You can use Azcopy https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-s3